# better games compatibility on Windows 2003

Tags: compatibility, directx, gaming, windows-server-2003

I think i have setup all the basic stuff required for gaming:
[direct3d acceleration](http://www.msfn.org/win2k3/hardwareacc.htm), disabled DEP on all programs, etc.
but, some XP-compatible games are still crashing without showing any error:

- Sonic Heroes
- Billy Hatcher
- ... (others)

Is there any system policy that could block them?

Comment: Windows 2003 the Server OS? Not really designed for running games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many software vendors are known to them only by delusional reasons, decide on what platform will run a custom application, in this case the game. And they are often protected by a primitive way, through the recognition version of the operating system, or worse using the header of the executable file that can be cut for the performance of the system under `Windows Vista\7` - `Windows 2008\2008 R2`.

Problems type error memory read / write is a problem with the malfunctioning of the resources of the program and the operating system. Put simply bad programming from the application developer leads to crash the application in the protection of `DEP`. Yes, you can remove this problem lowering the security of its operating system with the command:

```
 bootcfg /raw "/noexecute=alwaysoff /fastdetect" / id 1
```

or by editing the `boot.ini` changing or add option `/noexecute=alwaysoff`

Problems with the protection of determining the version of the operating system can be bypassed by changing registry keys in the sections:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
CSDBuildNumber, CSDVersion, CurrentBuildNumber, CurrentVersion, ProductName - REG_SZ

BuildLab, CurrentBuild, CurrentType  - REG_SZ

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSetххх\Control\ProductOption
ProductSuite REG_SZ , ProductType REG_SZ, Brand DWORD
```

Problems installing 32 bit drivers on a 64 bit system:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup
DisableDecoratedModelsRequirement  1    DWORD
```

Simple way:

[image: Microsoft Application Verifier pic 1]

[image: Microsoft Application Verifier setup OS version section]

You can use [Microsoft Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028) for a specific application to replace the operating system information. Sometimes it helps to setting the values to 0.

[image: Microsoft Application Verifier masquaring OS]

Or the right option that says the application that the operating system Windows XP SP3 despite the fact, what the real system.

[image: Microsoft Application Verifier masquaring OS and set Windows XP SP3]

Comment: "noexecute=alwaysoff" fixed some games, i've also installed this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3439

Comment: @eadmaster This is a multi-system mechanism to ensure compatibility with various applications http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=kb2492386 See the series of articles "Secrets of the Application Compatilibity Database(SDB)" http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=40. Thank you, good point.